# Create a toolbar with a second line in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Is it possible to create a second line in a Toolbar in SwiftUI like in Preview?

[image: Toolbar]

Comment: That appears to just be a custom 'toolbar' as part of Preview itself. You can recreate it with an `HStack` with your `Button`s inside and `Divider()` to separate items.

Comment: You mean a `VStack`? I tried that by the way with a `Divider()`, but it doesn't increase the height of the toolbar.

Comment: I mean that you can have the actual toolbar on the top, and then you can have an `HStack` containing all the items for your own custom bar. The `Divider()` view is the line in between to visually separate views. This can be set to a fixed height with `.frame(height: 50)` or can be dynamic. You can then align this `HStack` at the top of the screen, using `VStack { HStack { ... }  \n  Spacer() }` for example.

Comment: That's not working. Adding a `.frame(height: ...)` doesn't resize the toolbar. It only resizes the `VStack`.